# dimension of fiber product of k-schemes of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Görtz and Wedhorn Algebraic Geometry I, I have a question about the proof of

[image]

I don't understand why the final map is still injective.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working over a field, every $k$-module is flat. Since $k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ is injective, so is $$k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\otimes k[T_{m+1},\ldots,T_{m+n}]\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X) \otimes k[T_{m+1},\ldots,T_{m+n}].$$ Similarly, since $k[T_{m+1},\ldots,T_{m+n}]\to \Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)$ is injective, so is $$\Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)\otimes k[T_{m+1},\ldots,T_{m+n}]\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)\otimes \Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y).$$ Now the map $k[T_1,\ldots,T_{n+m}]\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X)\otimes \Gamma(Y,\mathscr{O}_Y)$ is just the composition of these two injective morphisms.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much!